# MYSQL: Group Concat not function

Tags: mysql

I want to use group_concate in my queries. I have two tables which are wla_user and wla_factory. In table wla_user, the column factory_id contains 1,8, while at wla_factory, id 1= factory 1 while id 8 = factory 8. While during the query, column factory_name, only show factory 1.

What I want is suppose factory 1, factory 8. Below is my current code:

```
SELECT wla_user.id, wla_user.name, wla_user.email, GROUP_CONCAT(wla_user.factory_id), GROUP_CONCAT(wla_factory.factory_name)
FROM wla_user 
INNER JOIN wla_factory ON wla_user.factory_id = wla_factory.id 
WHERE wla_user.email = 'me@gmail.com' AND wla_user.status = 1 GROUP BY wla_user.id
```

Can anyone know which part I missed?

Comment: `.. FROM .. JOIN .. ON FIND_IN_SET(wla_factory.id, wla_user.factory_id) ..` But I recommend you to normalize your data and move the relation `(user_id, factory_id)` to separate table. *MYSQL: Group Concat **not function*** What does the marked words should mean?

Comment: @Akina Can u give an example code here? Sorry im quite new

Comment: Provide sample source data ([Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), #5) and desired output for it (#3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not 100% sure that my understanding of your question is correct. I am assuming the below sample data with CSV value for `wla_user.factory_id`:

**wla_user**

| id | name | email | status | factory_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 | user1@example.com | 1 | 1,8 |
| 2 | user 2 | user2@example.com | 1 | 2,7 |

**wla_factory**

| id | factory_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | factory 1 |
| 2 | factory 2 |
| ... | ... |
| 7 | factory 7 |
| 8 | factory 8 |

Your current join `wla_user.factory_id = wla_factory.id` leads to `wla_user.factory_id` being implicitly cast to an integer, which is why you are only seeing one value from the `wla_factory` table.

As pointed out by Akina, you can use [FIND_IN_SET()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) to join based on your CSV column:

```
SELECT wla_user.id, wla_user.name, wla_user.email, wla_user.factory_id, GROUP_CONCAT(wla_factory.factory_name)
FROM wla_user
INNER JOIN wla_factory ON FIND_IN_SET(wla_factory.id, wla_user.factory_id)
WHERE wla_user.email = 'user1@example.com'
AND wla_user.status = 1
GROUP BY wla_user.id
```

The above query will work but, again as pointed out by Akina, you should normalise your data. Working with serialised data in columns is problematic (hard to query, cannot use indices, etc) when you need to query based on that data. Instead you should move the relation to a many-to-many table:

```
CREATE TABLE wla_user_factory (
    user_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    factory_id SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, factory_id),
    INDEX (factory_id, user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES wla_user (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (factory_id) REFERENCES wla_factory (id)
);
```

| user_id | factory_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 8 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 7 |

Then your query becomes:

```
SELECT
    u.id, u.name, u.email,
    GROUP_CONCAT(f.id ORDER BY f.id) AS factory_ids,
    GROUP_CONCAT(f.factory_name ORDER BY f.id) AS factory_names
FROM wla_user u
INNER JOIN wla_user_factory uf ON u.id = uf.user_id
INNER JOIN wla_factory f ON uf.factory_id = f.id
WHERE u.email = 'user1@example.com'
AND u.status = 1
GROUP BY u.id;
```

And the output is:

| id | name | email | factory_ids | factory_names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user 1 | user1@example.com | 1,8 | factory 1,factory 8 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lFlSHTos)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there, your refined query will be:

```
SELECT wla_user.id, wla_user.name, wla_user.email, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wla_user.factory_id), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wla_factory.factory_name)
FROM wla_user 
INNER JOIN wla_factory ON wla_user.factory_id = wla_factory.id 
WHERE wla_user.email = 'me@gmail.com' AND wla_user.status = 1 GROUP BY wla_user.id
```

The resource to refer to:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

Hope this helps.

Comment: still cannot. the factory name only show 1. Suppose 2